# Error: Unexpected request: GET app/js/help/city.json jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

**EDITED:**

I m trying to write a test for $on event in angularJs controller

This is my function :

```
  $scope.$on('$contentLoaded', function () {
                    MapsGoogle.init('France');
                    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid = false;
                    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed = false;
                });
```

and this is how I've done the test :

```
it('should set $rootScope.settings.layout properties to false', function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$contentLoaded');
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(MapsGoogle.init).toHaveBeenCalledWith('France');
            expect($rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid).toBe(false);
            expect($rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed).toBe(false);
        });
```

But after running the test I get this error :

> Error: Unexpected request: GET app/js/help/city.json
>       No more request expected

Can someone help me please?

***edit :*** I try to write another test in the same controller for another function and I get the same error The test case is :

```
 it('sets call changePicl function', function() {
          $scope.changePicl(event);
          $httpBackend.expectPOST('city/upload').respond(200,{data: {data: "somthing"}});
          $httpBackend.flush();

        });
```

I do exactly the same thing I do before but this time the test failed and I get this message :

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET app/js/help/city.json
    Expected POST city/upload
```

Comment: What did your `MapsGoogle.init` does ? It sounds like this function make the unexpected request

Comment: Yes @Pierre-Alexandre Moller I think the same but I have no idea how can I resolve this issue.It initialize geolocation section in my application